# Jquery Steps doing nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I`m trying to use Jquery-Steps but this doesnt even like is working or loaded, it only shows the h1 and div blocks, only the html is been loaded

Here is the code that I took from them, I dont know if I need to do something else.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type='text/javascript'  src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.steps.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'  src="jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $("#wizard").steps();
    </script>
    <div id="wizard">
<h1>First Step</h1>
<div>First Content</div>

<h1>Second Step</h1>
<div>Second Content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've included `steps.js` twice ?

Comment: Also, you're running the code before the elements are available in the DOM

Comment: With one or two it doesnt work, I will search about DOM but I'm very new to js so if you could explain I will be appreciated

Comment: Put your script tag at the *bottom* of the body. Otherwise, the elements won't be loaded yet. Also, open your dev console (hit F12). You'll see errors that will help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: please see my answer and upvote it ^_^ ! @GuilhermeFaria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try now ?**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <script>
            $("#wizard").steps();
        </script>
        <div id="wizard">
    <h1>First Step</h1>
    <div>First Content</div>
 
    <h1>Second Step</h1>
    <div>Second Content</div>
</div>
   <script>
    // Initialize wizard
var wizard = $("#wizard").steps();
 
// Add step
wizard.steps("add", {
    title: "HTML code", 
    content: "<strong>HTML code</strong>"
});
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working, well not exactly like the examples on the site I dont know how to apply styles over there. I think its not simples as I tought thank you

Comment: I will add you some styles but please accept my answer as a right one ^_^